# Is Ghost Adventures Scripted?

Tags: ghost-adventures

I don't know if Ghost Adventures is scripted or not. A lot of things have happened to me that are paranormal, it just seems like most of the time in the show, they seem off. I know that there is a lot of energy there at most of the places they go to but, I'm just not too sure if Ghost Adventures is scripted.

Answer (score 0):

All television shows that present themselves as "Reality" are scripted to some extent. Even competition shows like *Survivor* or *the Amazing Race* employs a staff of Writers to provide structure to how each episode will go. Take a look at the IMDb credits for *Ghost Adventures*, and you'll find a team of at least seven Writers. This is certainly a requirement for any show that features flashback segments and historical recreations.

The real question then is how much of the supposedly improvised portions of the show are genuine reactions to the environment, or just the hosts performing for the audience. If you believe former host Aaron Goodwin, there is a large degree of dramatization involved, including sending the cast back for reshoots to pretend to react to things that never actually happened. You can read more about Goodwin's accusations in this [Empire Weekly article](http://empirenews.net/ghost-adventures-star-gets-fired-reveals-disappointing-truth-about-paranormal-television-series/).